# Cant stop ordered lists from overlapping with anything I try to put below it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

```js
function search_games() {
    let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
    input=input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('games');
      
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            x[i].style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            x[i].style.display="block";                 
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.topnav {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #111;}

ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #ffffff;}

ul.topnav li.right {float: left;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul.topnav li.right, 
  ul.topnav li {float: none;}
}
#MENSIS {
  background-image: url("Images/lady-maria-bloodborne-4k.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;  
  background-position: center;
}
.h1brain {
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-top: 270px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  color: white;
}
#searchbar {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

input[type=text] {
   width: 30%;
   -webkit-transition: width 0.15s ease-in-out;
   transition: width 0.15s ease-in-out;
}


#list{
 font-size:  1.5em;
 margin-left: 90px;
 margin-right: 90px;
}

.games{
display: block;   
} 
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
#nostyle {
  list-style-type: none;
}
/*
#bakugan {
  background-image: url("Images/bloodborne-ohotnik-mech-pila.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;  
  background-position: center;

}*/
.pyrus {
  background-color: light-grey;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="bakugan">
      
<head>
    <title>
        Creating Search Bar using HTML
        CSS and Javascript
    </title>
      
    <!-- linking the stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
  
<body>
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./games.html">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <input id="searchbar" onkeyup="search_games()" type="text"
        name="search" placeholder="Search images..">
      </ul>
      

      
    <!-- link javascript -->
    <script src="./style.js"></script>

<!-- ordered list -->

 <h1 class="pyrus">Sample</h1>






<ol id='list'>
    
        <li class="games" id="nostyle"><a target="_blank" href="img_5terre.jpg"><div class="gallery">
          <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/megaman/images/d/d0/MM2AirMan.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/250?cb=20110314220902" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">airman4</div>
      </div>
      </li>
         <li class="games" id="nostyle"><a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg"><div class="gallery">
          <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/megaman/images/d/d0/MM2AirMan.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/250?cb=20110314220902" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">airman3</div>
      </div>
      </li>
        <li class="games" id="nostyle"><div class="gallery">
          <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/megaman/images/d/d0/MM2AirMan.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/250?cb=20110314220902" alt="Northern" width="600" height="400">
        
        <div class="desc">airman2</div>
      </div>
      </li>
        <li class="games" id="nostyle"><a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg"><div class="gallery">
          <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/megaman/images/d/d0/MM2AirMan.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/250?cb=20110314220902" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">airman1</div>
      </div></li>
</ol>

<h1 class="pyrus">Sample</h1>

</body>
  
</html>
```

I'm trying to get the sample text to appear below the ordered list of images (not the nav bar) similar to the sample text at the top but I can't stop it from overlapping. I've tried using positioning, margins, etc but nothing from the internet is working for me. I could just use `<br>` or margins but I want my `<h1>` elements to be relative to the images on the page.

Comment: Looks like you're not closing the `<div>` tags inside your `<a>` tags.

Comment: Please edit it and use the snippet tool shown as `<>`

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you use `float`, if you want to use float then you have to blindly `clearfix` or clear float so that the element doesn't collapse,
You can read more here [W3School clear float](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp)

here I made a clear float by adding `overflow: auto;` , on the `.pyrus` class

```js
function search_games() {
    let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
    input=input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('games');
      
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            x[i].style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            x[i].style.display="block";                 
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.topnav {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #111;}

ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #ffffff;}

ul.topnav li.right {float: left;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul.topnav li.right, 
  ul.topnav li {float: none;}
}
#MENSIS {
  background-image: url("Images/lady-maria-bloodborne-4k.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;  
  background-position: center;
}
.h1brain {
  border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin-top: 270px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  color: white;
}
#searchbar {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

input[type=text] {
   width: 30%;
   -webkit-transition: width 0.15s ease-in-out;
   transition: width 0.15s ease-in-out;
}


#list{
 font-size:  1.5em;
 margin-left: 90px;
 margin-right: 90px;
}

.games{
display: block;   
} 
div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
#nostyle {
  list-style-type: none;
}
/*
#bakugan {
  background-image: url("Images/bloodborne-ohotnik-mech-pila.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;  
  background-position: center;

}*/
.pyrus {
  background-color: light-grey;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  position: static;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="bakugan">
      
<head>
    <title>
        Creating Search Bar using HTML
        CSS and Javascript
    </title>
      
    <!-- linking the stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
</head>
  
<body>
    <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./games.html">Images</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="right"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <input id="searchbar" onkeyup="search_games()" type="text"
        name="search" placeholder="Search images..">
      </ul>
      

      
    <!-- link javascript -->
    <script src="./style.js"></script>

<!-- ordered list -->

 <h1 class="pyrus">Sample</h1>






<ol id='list'>
    
        <li class="games" id="nostyle"><a target="_blank" href="img_5terre.jpg"><div class="gallery">
          <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/megaman/images/d/d0/MM2AirMan.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/250?cb=20110314220902" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">airman4</div>
      </div>
      </li>
         <li class="games" id="nostyle"><a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg"><div class="gallery">
          <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/megaman/images/d/d0/MM2AirMan.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/250?cb=20110314220902" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">airman3</div>
      </div>
      </li>
        <li class="games" id="nostyle"><div class="gallery">
          <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/megaman/images/d/d0/MM2AirMan.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/250?cb=20110314220902" alt="Northern" width="600" height="400">
        
        <div class="desc">airman2</div>
      </div>
      </li>
        <li class="games" id="nostyle"><a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg"><div class="gallery">
          <img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/megaman/images/d/d0/MM2AirMan.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/250?cb=20110314220902" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc">airman1</div>
      </div></li>
</ol>

<h1 class="pyrus">Sample</h1>

</body>
  
</html>
```